# a 10px slide down bar on the top of the activity

Tags: java, android, user-interface, popup

I am making this **single Player** and **multi Player** game using Java Android ,so that when a ***userA*** sends invitation to ***userB*** while ***userB*** is during a single Player game, i want a slided-down bar to appear for ***userB*** , telling him about the invitation and which will be "**clickable**"..

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: are you looking for a sliding view over action bar ?

Comment: like FunRun game , when somebody invites you for a game there's a small bar slided down frop the top screen,

Comment: I can help you for sliding view over action bar same as `PullToRefresh` but not using `PullToRefresh Library` because its deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a view initially whoes top would be at -10, when you receive notification just do a trasnslate animation on it, repositioning it to new top 0, have height of your view as 10. It wont be that hard i  Guess.

Do some implementation, and comeback with code if it doesnt work out will help you.

Comment: great, i will start working on what you've said get you back on that if it works for me , if i find it complicated i will post the code, THANKS